# Getting this error when installing gems in aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, aptana, radrails

Getting this error when update/install gem Aptana radrails

ruby~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i686-linux]

rails -v
Rails 5.0.0

---

> Welcome to the Rails Shell. This view is meant for advanced users and
>   command line lovers as a text-based way to run rails commands such as:
>   rails, script/generate, script/plugin, gem, rake, etc. This shell can
>   replace the functionality of the Rake Tasks, Rails Plugins, and
>   generators views.
>
> > gem install -l mongrel-1.1.5.gem ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
> >         Unable to resolve dependencies: mongrel requires daemons (>= 1.0.3)
> >     gem install -l sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1.gem Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
> >     sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1.gem:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot
> ```
>
> load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'    from
>   extconf.rb:1:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out
>
> > gem install -l linecache-0.43.gem Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing linecache-0.43.gem:
> >       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot
> ```
>
> load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'    from
>   extconf.rb:1:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.43 for inspection. Results logged
>   to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache-0.43/ext/gem_make.out
>
> > gem install -l ruby-debug-base-0.10.3.gem ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
> >         Unable to resolve dependencies: ruby-debug-base requires linecache (>= 0.3)
> >     gem install -l ruby-debug-ide-0.4.5.gem ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
> >         Unable to resolve dependencies: ruby-debug-ide requires ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.3.0)